# Bash, pattern substitution for json-like multiline string

Tags: bash, awk

I wrote a bash script that essentially turns df -a command into multiple, new-line separated, Json formatted objects.

```
PATTERN='!/loop/ && /^\// {printf \
"\"disk.device\":\"%s\","\
"\"disk.mount\":\"%s\","\
"\"disk.total\":%d,"\
"\"disk.used\":%d,"\
"\"disk.free\":%d,"\
"\"disk.percentage\":%.2f\n", $1, $6, $2, $2-$4, $4, ($2-$4)/($2+1)*100}'

MODE=""
NAME="disk.device"
PAYLOAD="$(df -a | awk "$PATTERN")"

jsonify.sh $MODE "$PAYLOAD"
```

The script works in two steps:

- creating a "proto-json" payload
- converting it into actual json

The `$PAYLOAD` variable is constructed via awk and then passed to the jsonify function.

Here is an example output:

```
"disk.device":"/dev/nvme0n1p2","disk.mount":"/","disk.total":47745772,"disk.used":29455764,"disk.free":18290008,"disk.percentage":61,69
"disk.device":"/dev/nvme0n1p1","disk.mount":"/boot/efi","disk.total":583544,"disk.used":5356,"disk.free":578188,"disk.percentage":0,92
"disk.device":"/dev/nvme0n1p4","disk.mount":"/home","disk.total":427115864,"disk.used":46328340,"disk.free":380787524,"disk.percentage":10,85
"disk.device":"/dev/fuse","disk.mount":"/run/user/1000/doc","disk.total":0,"disk.used":0,"disk.free":0,"disk.percentage":0,00
```

Unfortunately a new requirement emerged, and now the value of the `"disk.device"` needs to be substituted from the actual name of the disk to `disk_n`, where n is an integer.

In the above example the result would look like:

```
"disk.device":"disk_0","disk.mount":"/","disk.total":47745772,"disk.used":29455764,"disk.free":18290008,"disk.percentage":61,69
"disk.device":"disk_1","disk.mount":"/boot/efi","disk.total":583544,"disk.used":5356,"disk.free":578188,"disk.percentage":0,92
"disk.device":"disk_2","disk.mount":"/home","disk.total":427115864,"disk.used":46328340,"disk.free":380787524,"disk.percentage":10,85
"disk.device":"disk_3","disk.mount":"/run/user/1000/doc","disk.total":0,"disk.used":0,"disk.free":0,"disk.percentage":0,00
```

Is it possible to work out a solution using a single command (maybe awk?) or do i need an explicit loop that goes trough all the lines of the payload? In case of the latter
how would you proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
echo "$output" | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{
    disk_n = "disk_" (NR - 1)
    sub(/"[^"]+"$/, "\"" disk_n "\"", $1)
    print
}'
```

Comment: it works like a charm, thanks! Could you elaborate a little bit the regex inside the sub?

Comment: Look for a double quote followed by one or more non-quotes followed by a double quote at the end of the string. It matches the `"/dev/nvme0n1p2"` part of `"disk.device":"/dev/nvme0n1p2"`

Comment: would this work if the "disk.device" is not the first one ?

Comment: No, I'm assuming it's in the first comma-separated field. As per your sample input. If it can be anywhere, do `sub(/"disk.device"."[^"]+"/, "\"disk.device\":\"" disk_n "\"")` -- omitting the 3rd argument so that substitution happens anywhere in $0, in which case you can remove the `-F` and `-v` options.

Comment: Is it possible to turn it into something that looks for a double quote encased string following ```"disk.device":``` ?

Answer (score 0):

In GNU `AWK` one might use postincrease to get running number starting at zero, consider following example, let `file.txt` content be

```
100
1000
10
10000
1
100000
```

and you want to output ordinal followed by numer for values >= 500, then you might do

```
awk '$1>=500{printf "%d %s\n", i++, $1}' file.txt
```

which gives output

```
0 1000
1 10000
2 100000
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*